# Angularjs applying $watch to cellTemplate function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am showing data to user using angular `ui-grid`. In the following code for field '`plan`', i add a set of entities by calling the `getPlan()` function and show it using a cellTemplate in ui-grid columnDefs.

```
$scope.getPlan = function(rowEntity) {

            var plan1Temp = rowEntity.plan1;
            var plan2Temp = rowEntity.plan2;
            var plan3Temp = rowEntity.plan3;
            var plan4Temp = rowEntity.plan4;
            var plan5Temp = rowEntity.plan5;
            var plan6Temp = rowEntity.plan6;
            var plan7Temp = rowEntity.plan7;
            var plan8Temp = rowEntity.plan8;

            plan = plan1Temp+plan2Temp+plan3Temp+plan4Temp+plan5Temp+plan6Temp+plan7Temp+plan8Temp;
            console.log("plan=", plan);
            return plan;
        };

  columnDefs: [{ field        : 'plan',
                 cellTemplate : '<div id="grid-cell-template">
                                    {{grid.appScope.getPlan(row.entity)}}</div>',
              displayName     : "Plan",
      footerCellTemplate      : '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
                                     \Total:\ {{grid.appScope.getTotalPlan() }}</div>',
                        width : "*"
             }]
```

Then to show the total of all the plans i use footerCellTemplate with getTotalPlan(). While using it i got `$digest() iterations reached` error. I noticed the getPlan() function is called many times. So i added $watch like shown below.

```
    var totalPlan = [];   
    $scope.$watch(function() { 
                    return plan;
                }, function() {
                    totalPlan.push(plan);
                    console.log("totalPlan =", totalPlan);
                });

$scope.getTotalPlan = function() {

                    var sum = 0;
                    angular.forEach(totalPlan ,function(item){
                        sum = sum + item;
                    });     
                    return sum;
                    console.log("getTotalPlan=", sum);
                };
```

After adding `$watch` also the `getPlan()` function is called many times. Also in `totalPlan[]` it holds only 2 values, first null and second one last record value(in total there are 3 records) and prints this value in the `ui-grid footercelltemplate`. How should i use $watch to make it work right?

So basically the problem is i am not able to insert '`plan`' values into `totalPlan[ ]` and show the total in the grid footer template.

Also i tried using `::` inside the expression, the number of `getPlan()` calling times reduced to half but no luck.